# Which is more efficient: binary & or logical &&

Tags: boolean, logical-operators, boolean-operations

When all values are boolean doesn't the binary `&` operate on more bits than the logical `&&`?

For example

```
if ( foo == "Yes" & 2 != 0 & 6 )
```

or

```
if ( foo == "Yes" && 2 != 0 && 6 )
```

(thinking PHP specifically, but any language will do)

Comment: It depends on the language.  Yes, really.

Comment: @SLaks An answer for any language would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How many bits it operates on is irrelevant: the processor can do it in a single instruction anyway (normally). The crucial difference is the shortcut-ability of `&&`, so for anything on the right hand side that's not trivial to evaluate it is faster — assuming a language where `&&` works this way, like C or Java. (And apparently PHP, though I know to little about it to be sure.)

On the other hand, the branch that this shortcut requires might also slow down things, however I'm quite sure nowadays' compilers are smart enough to optimize that away.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the logic of your code.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use && if && is logical and to use & when & is logical, that's why these operators are for. Don't optimize prematurely, because:

1. The speed of your application might be fine without optimization
2. You might optimize a part of your application and will win an irrelevant amount of speed increase
3. Your code will be more complicated and it will be difficult to work on later versions
4. If you have an issue with speed, it will probably not be related to the idea
5. Programming is quite difficult in itself sometimes and this kind of hack will make your code unreadable, your teammates will not understand your code and the overall efficiency of your team will be reduced because of ugly codes written by you

Comment: Right, though if `&&` _was_ slower in a way that the compiler couldn't compensate for, and it had been shown that one occurence was a bottleneck in the program, it would be ok to replace it with `&` there. With a comment, of course.